# TotalRevenue field returned by Quickbooks Online API is always NULL

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm using the PHP SDK for the Quickbooks Online v3 API.  I'm running query through DataService and QueryMessage that returns an array of objects, that contains entire customer-specific records.  Name/addresses/phone numbers/balance due/overdue balance etc.

Everything works just fine, however a key is given "TotalRevenue" and its value is always returned as "NULL".  I've played with the test data on QuickBooks Online, created several pre-dated transactions, and its always NULL regardless.  I can, however, manipulate Balance, OverDueBalance, and other accounting-related fields.  What is the problem with TotalRevenue?  I suspect Quickbooks has turned it off, for some reason...but I'd like confirmation :)

edit: I checked Quickbooks' Online API Explorer, and in their returns, it does not return "TotalRevenue" at all when querying the Customer table.

code:

```
    // Prep Data Services
    $dataService = new DataService($serviceContext);

    // Build a query
    $oneQuery = new QueryMessage();
    $oneQuery->sql = "SELECT";
    $oneQuery->entity = "Customer";
    $oneQuery->orderByClause = "FamilyName";
    $oneQuery->startposition = "1";
    $oneQuery->maxresults = "50";

    // Run a query
    $queryString = $oneQuery->getString();
    $entities = $dataService->Query($queryString);

    // Echo some formatted output
    var_dump($entities);
```

var_dump outputs:

```
    [0]=>
  object(IPPCustomer)#29 (62) {
    ["Taxable"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    ["BillAddr"]=>
    object(IPPPhysicalAddress)#68 (16) {
      ["Id"]=>
      string(4) "55555"
      ["Line1"]=>
      string(22) "123 ABC St"
      }

      ...

    ["Notes"]=>
    string(20) "These are some notes"
    ["Job"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["BillWithParent"]=>
    string(5) "false"

    ... 

    ["Balance"]=>
    string(5) "40.00"
    ["OpenBalanceDate"]=>
    NULL
    ["BalanceWithJobs"]=>
    string(5) "40.00"
    ["CreditLimit"]=>
    NULL
    ["AcctNum"]=>
    NULL
    ["CurrencyRef"]=>
    NULL
    ["OverDueBalance"]=>
    NULL
    ["TotalRevenue"]=>
    NULL   //<-----Why is this always NULL if there are transactions (both expenses
           //      and revenue) made from and to the customers?

    ...

    ["GivenName"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["MiddleName"]=>
    string(6) "Middle"
    ["FamilyName"]=>
    string(10) "Doe"

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 PHP devkit is a wrapper on top of QBD and QBO API.

'**TotalRevenue**' is for QBD. QBD REST APIs are depricated. In future PHP devkit releases, this field will not present. Please ignore this field.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_deprecated/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/030_entity_services_reference/customer

As you have mentioned, this field is not present for QBO V3.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

Thanks